# Checking if WooCommerce is active and what version is used

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, version

I need to check if WooCommerce is active and check its version number to make it work differently for new and old versions.

I found that `WC_VERSION` stores version number, so if it exists, it also means that WooCommerce is active. The problem is that it can return anything only after plugins are loaded. I would like to check version and then use outside `woocommerce_ver_check function` in general scope. Can I do it without global variables?

I want to do something like this, but `woocommerce_ver_check()` is always null, because it executes after WooCommerce is loaded, unlike the rest of the code which is not assigned to any hook:

```
// Check WooCommerce version.
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_ver_check');
function woocommerce_ver_check() {
    if (defined('WC_VERSION')) return WC_VERSION; 
}

// Only if WooCommerce is active.
if (! woocommerce_ver_check() == null  ) {
    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '>=' ) ) {
        // new version code
    } else {
        // old version code
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to better explain what you'd like to achieve, and why the function you have is not suitable.

Comment: I made some progress troubleshooting and overhauled contents of my original post. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to use the following (that is used for WooCommerce third party plugins):

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
        // Old version code (example)
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->id
    } else {
        // New version code (example)
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
    }
}
```

For new WooCommerce 3 CRUD Object methods you can also use `method_exists()` like for example:

```
$order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
```

Comment: I used the same originally, but it doesn't properly handle the case when I installed WooCommerce from GitHub on my test site and it has path woocommerce-2.6.0/woocommerce.php. Partial match is prone to fail as some plugins use 
"woocommerce" first in its slug

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk It's bad faith… Sorry, but this doesn't fail on normal WooCommerce installations and it's used by a lot of official WoCommerce third party plugins. The case that you describe is not a normal behavior and it's more related to a hacking case as people doesn't download Woocommerce from github. Additionally, `in_array()` will not match with other plugins that    use "woocommerce" first in its slug…

Comment: I meant that it would fail if I somehow tried to add wildcard after slug. You are right, I sometimes want things too perfect, while I should simply change folder name to "woocommerce" for GitHub installations (needed for <3.0 which is not available on repo), assume that others download from repository and move on.

Comment: woocommerce documentation says it works https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installing-uninstalling-woocommerce/#section-4 @LoicTheAztec